# Getting IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds when attempting to apply technical indicators to a pandas DataFrame of stock info

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

I'm new-ish to python and am having some trouble using the pandas_ta extension to apply a few technical indicators to a dataframe of stock info. The original dataframe 'nonStockdf' is structured with columns

```
['index', 'date', 'ticker', 'adj_close', 'close', 'open', 'high', 'low',
       'volume', 'EMA_9', 'EMA_50', 'EMA_200', 'RSI_14', 'MACD_12_26_9',
       'MACDH_12_26_9', 'MACDS_12_26_9'],
      dtype='object')
```

and has historical data for about 50 stocks, indices and futures going back 5 years. I am attempting to apply some technical indicators as new columns to the existing DataFrame and save in a new dataframe called `nonStockTechsdf` but keep getting `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. Can anyone help?? My code is below. Thanks in advance

```
ETF_Daily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

nonStockTechsdf = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ETF_Daily:
    df = nonStockdf.loc[nonStockdf['ticker'] == i]
    df.ta.ema('close', length=9, append=True)
    df.ta.ema('close', length=50, append=True)
    df.ta.ema('close',length=200, append=True)
    df.ta.rsi('close',n=14, append=True)
    df.ta.macd('close',slow=26, fast=12, sign=9, append=True)
    nonStockTechsdf = nonStockTechsdf.append(df)
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  I was getting the IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds because of the df.ta.ema('close',length=200, append=True) line.  That line calculates the 200-day exponential moving average and, as such, requires at least 200 days worth of data for each individual stock in the dataframe to calculate correctly.  The first stock that it hit with less than 200 days worth of data raised that error.  I fixed this by adding a IF statements like so: